# Proper formatting of post_date for wp_insert_post?

Tags: date-time, wp-insert-post

What is the proper way to define the post date when submitting a post from the front end using [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) ([Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/post.php#L2378))?

My snippet now is publishing with the mysql time...

```
if (isset ($_POST['date'])) {
    $postdate = $_POST['Y-m-d'];
}
else {
    $postdate = $_POST['2011-12-21'];
}

// ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
'post_title'    =>   $title,
'post_content'  =>   $description,
'post_date'     =>   $postdate,
'post_status'   =>   'publish',
'post_parent' => $parent_id,
'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
);

//SAVE THE POST
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you don't add a post_date then WordPress fills it automatically with the current date and time.

To set another date and time `[ Y-m-d H:i:s ]` is the right structure. An example below with your code.

```
$postdate = '2010-02-23 18:57:33';

$new_post = array(
   'post_title'    =>   $title,
   'post_content'  =>   $description,
   'post_date'     =>   $postdate,
   'post_status'   =>   'publish',
   'post_parent'   =>   $parent_id,
   'post_author'   =>   get_current_user_id(),
);

//SAVE THE POST
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! Adding `$postdate = date('2010-02-23 18:57:33');` actually makes input boxes stop functioning, perhaps that's just a bug in Chrome though...

Comment: I've tried it myself and it works. Maybe your problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I tried using that date formating, and it is returning `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4028`

Comment: should be `$postdate = '2010-02-23 18:57:33';`, because `date()` requires literal date format to process, not numbers. Or `$postdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2010-02-23 18:57:33'));`

Answer (score 6):

to convert your date into Wordpress (MySQL DATETIME) format, try this:

```
$date_string = "Sept 11, 2001"; // or any string like "20110911" or "2011-09-11"
// returns: string(13) "Sept 11, 2001"

$date_stamp = strtotime($date_string);
// returns: int(1000166400)

$postdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date_stamp);
// returns: string(19) "2001-09-11 00:00:00"

$new_post = array(
    // your other arguments
   'post_date'     =>   $postdate
);

$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

or course if you want to really be sexy do this:

```
'post_date'     => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("Sept 11, 2001"))
```

Comment: This is very helpful for formatting a Unix timestamp, specifically the `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date_stamp)` code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't format the `$_POST['date']` like this... You'll have to run the *value* from `$_POST['date']` through something like `$postdate = date( $_POST['date'] )`... There's also the possibility to call get_option for the blog settings. See Option Reference in Codex.

Comment: Using Date actually broke the posting and would return a 404 error. Thanks Kaiser for the direction though!

Answer (score 2):

For the community here is my final working code:

header

```
$year = $_REQUEST['year'];
$month = $_REQUEST['month'];
$day = $_REQUEST['day'];
$postdate =  $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day . " 08:00:00";

$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    =>  $title,
    'post_content'  =>  $description,
    'post_status'   =>  'publish',
    'post_author'   =>  get_current_user_id(),
    'post_date'     =>  $postdate
);
```

Answer (score 2):

came across thru google. i know its old but there is no definite answer. wordpress code uses `current_time( 'mysql' )` to save date/time in wp_update_post function! this will generate the desired date format.